# add termmeta field to woocommerce attribute in rest api result

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api, headless-cms

I have woo variation swatches plugin on my website and I want to use woocommerce and wordpress in a headless project. my problem is when I want to fetch attribute terms via

**/wp-json/wc/v3/products/attributes/COLOR_ATTRIBUTE_ID/terms**

the returned result doesn't include the color code field. I know the color code is stored in **termmeta** table with **product_attribute_color** key. is there any way to add this meta as a field to the attributes result in rest API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend with `woocommerce_rest_prepare_(taxonomy)` hooks like this -

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_prepare_pa_color', 'add_custom_data_to_product_attributes_terms', 10, 3 ); // where "taxonomy" = "pa_color" as taxonomy name

// filter the product response here
function add_custom_data_to_product_attributes_terms( $response, $post, $request ) {
    
    // $response->data['color-code'] = $response->data['description'];
    // execute all here
    
    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted the correct code for my own question, Lowin Ko Ko's answers helped me to find the solution but because his code is psuedo code I posted my code here.

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_rest_prepare_pa_color', 'add_color_meta', 10, 3);

if(!function_exists('add_color_meta')) {
    function add_color_meta($response, $term) {
        $response->data['color_code'] = get_term_meta($term->term_id,'product_attribute_color');
        return $response;
    }
}
```